# How do I iterate through all possible pairs of characters using pair?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

What I'm trying to do is to initialize all the values of a `map<pair<char, char>, double>` to 1 where the char's in the pair only consist of lower case alphabets and space.

I.e. I want to initialize all map m['a', 'a'] m['a', 'b'] ... m['z', 'z'] to 1. Is there any easy way to do this?

If it helps, I am trying to decrypt a message that is encrypted using substitution cipher and I have to create bigrams for all the alphabet pairs.

Comment: Use 2 for loops. Go for the easiest solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; ++i){
    for (char j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; ++j){
        m[std::make_pair(i, j)] = 1;
    }
}
```

will be difficult to better, for the sake of clarity at least.

Comment: And no one to say that there might have non lower character between `'a'` and `'z'` as for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC :-)

Comment: @Jarod42: A full-generality answer would be heavily upvoted. All yours ;-)

Comment: I added it, wonder how to make the initialization cleaner btw, using `boost` is a little better [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67af25868af73180) but heavy tool for that :-/.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like this:

```
for(char i = 'a'; i<='z'; i++){
    for(char j = 'a'; j<='z'; j++){
        m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(i,j),1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Few days ago I also used the [] operator for initializing the members in a map<string,struct> with struct having only a parameterized constructor. It caused some errors and since then I prefer using this way.

Comment: Hum. That's interesting. That's a question in itself.

Answer (score 1):

To handle tricky cases where there are other characters between `'a'` and `'z'` (as for [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)), you may do:

```
std::map<std::pair<char, char>, double> m;
const auto letters = {
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
};
for (auto c1 : letters) {
    for (auto c2 : letters) {
        m.emplace(std::make_pair(c1, c2), 1.);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e786160ffb696cd)

Boost allows that initialization for `letters`:

```
const auto letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                     | boost::adaptors::sliced(0, 26); // remove trailling '\0'
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67af25868af73180)

Comment: Very thorough. The OP ought to accept this answer, in place of mine.